# Removing a mergeinfo revision number

Tags: svn, mergeinfo

I have the following revisions in the mergeinfo between two of my branches.

```
sh% svn mergeinfo --show-revs merged '^/trunk' '^/branches/myotherbranch'
r139784
r139796
r139883
r139944
r139953
r139994
r140005
```

And I want to remove one of the revisions from this list, so that I can attempt to do the merge again. How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Do a "reverse merge" of that revision. If you don't actually want to make any changes when you do this merge, you can specify "record only". Example:

```
svn merge -c -139994 --record-only
```

This should remove revision 139994 from your merge history without actually changing any files. If you want to actually undo the changes so you can try applying them again don't use "--record-only".

The -c option is your standard "cherry pick" merge except the negative revision number means to apply it in reverse.